# Dataset name could not be same in US and EU data location

Tags: google-bigquery, data-migration

I wonder why I could not create same Data Set name both in US and EU Data location. Also I have had trouble Migrating US Data Location of Big Query Tables to EU Data Location earlier.

I have identified 'save as table' option helped to recreate table that were in US to EU Data Location using temp Dataset, but doesn't help with huge tables.

could anyone let me know is there any way to create same Dataset name in EU as where in US ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within same project - you cannot create two datasets with the same name.

Comment: I didnt reliaze it couldnt be done in same project. Anyhow I have tried 'Save as Table' option through selecting table with limit 0 and created schema in EU temp dataset. Then recreate same dataset name in EU and  load to these tables.